# How Do I access a variable inside a variable inside a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I need to change the value of center inside my map function by assigning x to the lat object when a button is clicked. However,I can't seem to figure out how to assign map.center.lat = 43.138428 from my alertFunction. Essentially, I am asking how to reference an object, inside an object, inside a function, from another function. I am working inside Rails.

```
<script>
//function to update my center
function alertFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    initMap();
    **Wrong Code**
    **// map.center.lat = 43.138428;**
};

//function to start map
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center:{lat: 41.138428, lng:-85.140239},
    });
```

Comment: if i understood well, all you need is to do `return map;` in your `initMap` function and get the result when you call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `initMap` function should return something, or you can use a parameter to set `.lat`

```
// the latter
function alertFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    initMap(43.138428);
    //      ^ pass latitude value
};

//function to start map
function initMap(latitude) {
//               ^ parameter
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center:{lat: latitude, lng:-85.140239},
      //           ^ from parameter
  });
}

// the former
function alertFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var map = initMap();
    //        ^ initMap returns the map
    map.center.lat = 43.138428;
};

//function to start map
function initMap(latitude) {
 return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 10,
   center:{lat: latitude, lng:-85.140239},
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Maps doc they show it - you need to declare your 'map' variable outside of the function or it's not accessible by other functions.

```
    <script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
```

That way your initMap() is altering a variable outside of the initMap function.

Comment: oh man, I can't thank you enough for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//function to update my center
function alertFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var map = initMap();
    **Wrong Code**
    **// map.center.lat = 43.138428;**
};

//function to start map
  function initMap() {
    return map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center:{lat: 41.138428, lng:-85.140239},
    });
```

retrun map or you have to use global variable.